# How to drop a big table (175G) in aws rds mysql?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a big log table that saved 850 million data, but I plan to delete it now.
The single table used 175GB of disk space, I am worry that using `DROP TABLE` will exhausted disk IO is causing mysql to freeze, if it's a self-built mysql database, i can use hardware link to solve this problem, but how can i do in RDS?

Comment: Use truncate instead

Comment: Why would dropping a table cause massive disk I/O? What what is "hardware link"?

Comment: ln /data/mysql/testdb/test.ibd /data/mysql/testdb/test.ibd.hdlk

TRUNCATE=/usr/local/bin/truncate
for i in `seq 179200 -128 128 `; 
do 
  sleep 2
  $TRUNCATE -s ${i}MB /data/mysql/mytest/erp.ibd.hdlk 
done
rm -rf /data/mysql/testdb/test.ibd.hdlk ;

But this only used for self-built mysql